# Count number of times a word appears (dplyr)

Tags: r, regex, count, dplyr

Simple question here, perhaps a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776276/r-count-how-often-words-from-a-list-appear-in-a-sentence)?

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of times a word appears in a vector. I know I can count the number of rows a word appears in, as shown here:

```
temp <- tibble(idvar = 1:3, 
               response = (c("This sounds great",
                      "This is a great idea that sounds great",
                      "What a great idea")))
temp %>% count(grepl("great", response)) # lots of ways to do this line
# answer = 3
```

The answer in the code above is 3 since "great" appears in three rows. However, the word "great" appears 4 different times in the vector "response". How do I find that instead?

Comment: Are you planning to provide a specific word and get the number you want? Or you want to get that number for every word that appears in all sentences?

Comment: Just planning to provide a specific word and get the number. I can use `tidytext` unnest to split sentences into tokens and then count the words. (But if you have recommendations for a different way to do it, I'm all ears!)

Comment: I had `tidytext` in mind as well :)

Answer (score 3):

We could use `str_count` from `stringr` to get the number of instances having 'great' in each row and then get the `sum` of that count

```
library(tidyverse)
temp %>% 
   mutate(n = str_count(response, 'great')) %>%
   summarise(n = sum(n))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#      n
#   <int>
#1     4
```

---

Or using `regmatches/gregexpr` from `base R`

```
sum(lengths(regmatches(temp$response, gregexpr('great', temp$response))))
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition of `base R` - that may actually be simpler in some of my use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, this should solve your problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
temp$response %>% 
  str_extract_all('great') %>%
  unlist %>%
  length
```